# Weibull Density Plot (dimensions too large)

Tags: pgfplots, errors

I just would like to draw Weibull density plot with parameters 10 and 1.
But pgfplot gave me `dimensions too large` error. `restrict y to domain` didn't help.
Any help?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={f(\x,\a,\b)= (\a/\b)*(\x/\b)^(\a-1)*exp(-(\x/\b)^\a);}]
\begin{axis}[samples=150]
\addplot[color=blue]{f(x,10,1)};
\end{axis}                   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: adjust the default domain `-5:5` to `domain=0:2`

Comment: @percusse but why is `0:3` too large? `x^9` too much?

Comment: @percusse but when i write domain=0:10, it gives the same error.

Comment: @mert because `10^9` is rather big for LaTeXs math capabilities

Comment: @daleif Function definitions are handled by TikZ hence TeX precision. If inline plotted there won't be any problem for pgfplots (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, LaTeX can't handle the values which you will get in between the calculation. But you could use `gnuplot` to do the calculation. Please find in the following code two ways to do it. First using the `raw gnuplot` function and second "just" `gnuplot` with a previously defined command `\Weibull`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14 and gnuplot v5.0 patchlevel 3
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \newcommand*\Weibull[3]{(#2/#3)*(#1/#3)^(#2-1)*exp(-(#1/#3)^#2)}
        \begin{axis}[
            smooth,
        ]
            \addplot [color=blue,very thick] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
                % set number of samples
                set samples 100;
                f(x,a,b)= (a/b)*(x/b)**(a-1)*exp(-(x/b)**a);
                plot [x=0:2] f(x,10,1);
            };
            \addplot [color=red,very thick,dashed,samples=100,domain=0:2]
                gnuplot {\Weibull{x}{10}{1}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]